# Android: How to check if TextView is bold or italic programatically

Tags: android, textview

I would like to know how to construct an if statement to check if a TextView is bold or italic. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried something ?

Comment: i did. but is there a way to check if is both italic and bold?
i could check if it is either italic or bold

Comment: first tell us how do you set both italic and bold? And do not change your question. In the original you asked how to check .. `bold or italic` not you want `bald and italic`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getTypeface()

```
public Typeface getTypeface ()
```

returns:

> the current typeface and style in which the text is being displayed.

```
if(yourTextViewInstance.getTypeface()!=null){
   if(yourTextViewInstance.getTypeface().getStyle()==Typeface.BOLD || yourTextViewInstance.getTypeface().getStyle()==Typeface.ITALIC){
      //do your stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: `Typeface` also has the methods `isBold()` and `isItalic()` since API level 1.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
textView.getTypeface()
```

then check if it is equal to

- Typeface.BOLD
- Typeface.ITALIC
- Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC

Answer (score 2):

To check if textview is BOLD and ITALIC, use following code:

```
 if((textView.getTypeface().getStyle() & Typeface.BOLD)!=0 &&(textView.getTypeface().getStyle() & Typeface.ITALIC)!=0){
                  //do your stuff
```

}

To check if textview is either BOLD or ITALIC, use following code:

```
 if((textView.getTypeface().getStyle() & Typeface.BOLD)!=0 ||(textView.getTypeface().getStyle() & Typeface.ITALIC)!=0){
                      //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: @SpencerChantler123, was it useful?