# How to check that the Text is bold or not?

Tags: android, textview

I have set the Text TextView Bold and now want to check programmatically that the text is Bold or not.Please help me how to check it programmatically.
Actually I have too many TextViews in my layout so I first Find the instance to textView then check that is it bold, italic or normal.I have use the following code to check it dosent works application crashes

```
 private void findAllEdittexts(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    int count = viewGroup.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View view = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup)
            findAllEdittexts((ViewGroup) view);
        else if (view instanceof AutoFitTextView) {
            AutoFitTextView textView_ = (AutoFitTextView) view;
            String Temp__=textView_.getText().toString();
            Boolean temp_isBold=false;
            Boolean temp_isItalic=false;
            Boolean temp_isNorlmal=false;
            if(textView_.getTypeface().getStyle()==Typeface.BOLD)
                temp_isBold=true;
            if(textView_.getTypeface().getStyle()==Typeface.ITALIC)
                temp_isItalic=true;
            if(textView_.getTypeface().getStyle()==Typeface.NORMAL)
                temp_isNorlmal=true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18012403/android-how-to-check-if-textview-is-bold-or-italic-programatically

Comment: @MatterCat please check my post I have posted my code. I am totally lost I didn't find any problem in the code but the application crashes. Please help me

Comment: What's the crash error in logcat? Also, don't use `Boolean` unless you have a specific reason for it; use `boolean` (lowercase) instead.

Comment: @MatterCat There is an exception  java.lang.NullPointerException on this line  if(textView_.getTypeface().getStyle()==Typeface.BOLD)

Comment: Run through the debugger and check if anything's null. Put a breakpoint at  `          AutoFitTextView textView_ = (AutoFitTextView) view;` to see if `textView__` actually has a value. Split up `textView_.getTypeface().getStyle()` and check if `textView__.getTypeface()` or if the problem is the style part.

Comment: @MatterCat the problem occur when the string contain only white spaces

Comment: Then add a check for `if (Temp__.trim().length() > 0)` and place all your typeface checks in it.

Comment: @MatterCat Thanks problem is solved

Comment: @MatterCat can we check the TYPEFACE.BOLD  for punctuations?

Comment: You can use a regex if you want to test for more complex texts, but the trim should pass punctuation text just fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MatterCat for helping me to solve my problems.