# Edittext.getTypeFace returns null

Tags: android

I have bold text inside the edittext, but when I use. edittext.getTypeFace.isBold() ,it never becomes true. It is actually a null value. What is it I am doing wrong?

```
final EditText _etheadertext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etheader_text);

boolean style_bold = false ;

_btnbold.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            int startSelection = _etheadertext.getSelectionStart();
            int endSelection = _etheadertext.getSelectionEnd();
            if(startSelection>endSelection){
                startSelection = _etheadertext.getSelectionEnd();
                endSelection = _etheadertext.getSelectionStart();
            }
            Spannable s = _etheadertext.getText();
       s.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),     startSelection, endSelection, 0);
            _etheadertext.setText(s);
            _etheadertext.setSelection(startSelection, endSelection);

}

    });

_btntestprint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


           if(_etheadertext.getTypeface().isBold()){

                style_bold = true;
            }


}

    });
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: if the text is bold/italic or underlined I want to send that information to my thermal printer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18012457/10752944

Comment: That s what I referred to write my code, Still it is a null value

Comment: Can you update the question with your code?

Comment: I just did. Please point out what I have done wrong

Comment: Have you tried debugging and seeing whether the if condition returns true or false?

Comment: it returns false, because the initialised value is false . Yes I have debugged , it never goes inside the if condition.

Comment: you have 2 buttons? 
Can you try performing the if condition in the first button click and see if it works?

Comment: still the same result

Comment: `if(sampleTextView.getTypeface().getStyle() == Typeface.BOLD)
            is_bold = true;`  I tried something like this and my value got updated from false to true. Can you try the same?

Comment: It is not working for me though

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29504749/10752944

Comment: Use `Boolean` instead of `boolean`